# What is the difference between Character.isWhitespace(char) and Character.isSpaceChar(char)

Tags: java

Both of them returns true if it is empty char / white space or else it returns false.  My question is why java has both the methods as they are doing the same thing

Comment: Here is the Java Character API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html Please read both methods and you will see the difference...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Method `isSpaceChar(char)` is only for checking unicode space character (SPACE_SEPARATOR,LINE_SEPARATOR, PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR)  while method `isWhiteSpace(char)` is for space as well as other white space characters like tab,carriage return etc

```
char ch='\t';
System.out.println(Character.isWhitespace(ch));
System.out.println( Character.isSpaceChar(ch));
```

It outputs

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 3):

`isSpaceChar` will check if the char is a unicode space char while `isWhitespace` checks for any whitespace char. A character is a Java whitespace character if and only if it satisfies one of the following criteria:

```
It is a Unicode space character (SPACE_SEPARATOR, LINE_SEPARATOR, or PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR) but is not also a non-breaking space ('\u00A0', '\u2007', '\u202F').

It is '\t', U+0009 HORIZONTAL TABULATION.  
It is '\n', U+000A LINE FEED.  
It is '\u000B', U+000B VERTICAL TABULATION.  
It is '\f', U+000C FORM FEED.  
It is '\r', U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN.  
It is '\u001C', U+001C FILE SEPARATOR.  
It is '\u001D', U+001D GROUP SEPARATOR.  
It is '\u001E', U+001E RECORD SEPARATOR.  
It is '\u001F', U+001F UNIT SEPARATOR.
```

So there is overlap as isWhitespace will return true for Unicode space chars but also a whole load more.

See:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)

Answer (score 2):

The difference is spelled out in the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSpaceChar(char)):

> `isWhiteSpace`: Determines if the specified character is white space according to Java. A character is a Java whitespace character if and only if it satisfies one of the following criteria: [...]
>
> `isSpaceChar`: Determines if the specified character is a Unicode space character. A character is considered to be a space character if and only if it is specified to be a space character by the Unicode Standard.

These two definitions are different and depending on the use case you'll need one or the other. For simple needs you may not care about the difference, but clearly it's there.